# Dependency from DLL to own Import Library, how to avoid?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, dll, msbuild

I am building a proxy/stub library from an IDL file, and for some reason, the build driver believes that the import library generated during the link is an input file to the link, causing the project to be relinked every time (path names shortened for readability):

```
10:05:33.764 1>
Target "Link: (TargetId:66)" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.Targets" from project "[...]\VersionControl.vcxproj" (target "_Link" depends on it):
Using "Link" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Win32, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Link" (TaskId:26)
    Write Tracking Logs: (TaskId:26)
[...]
    Outputs for [...]\DEBUG\DLLDATA.OBJ|[...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.DLL.EMBED.MANIFEST.RES|[...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL_I.OBJ|[...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL_P.OBJ: (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.ILK (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.DLL (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.DLL.INTERMEDIATE.MANIFEST (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.PDB (TaskId:26)
    Inputs for [...]\DEBUG\DLLDATA.OBJ|[...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.DLL.EMBED.MANIFEST.RES|[...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL_I.OBJ|[...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL_P.OBJ: (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\RPCRT4.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\KERNEL32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\USER32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\GDI32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\WINSPOOL.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\COMDLG32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\ADVAPI32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\SHELL32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\OLE32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\OLEAUT32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\UUID.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\ODBC32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\ODBCCP32.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.DLL.EMBED.MANIFEST.RES (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\DLLDATA.OBJ (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL_I.OBJ (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL_P.OBJ (TaskId:26)
    [...]\SYSTEM32\TZRES.DLL (TaskId:26)
    [...]\SORTING\SORTDEFAULT.NLS (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.EXP (TaskId:26)
    [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\VERSIONCONTROL.DEF (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\MSVCRTD.LIB (TaskId:26)
    [...]\LIB\OLDNAMES.LIB (TaskId:26)
    Source compilation required: input [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.LIB is newer than output [...]\DEBUG\VERSIONCONTROL.DLL. (TaskId:26)
```

The project is set up as a normal DLL project, with settings left as defaults. Any idea why MSBuild decides that these generated files should be treated as inputs, and how I could fix this?

Comment: "VersionControl" is an unusual name for a proxy/stub DLL.  My crystal balls say that your main COM server project is named "VersionControl" as well.

Comment: No, that is just the interface name. Currently, the only implementation lives in the main app, and COM is only used to move long-running operations into a separate thread. At some point, I plan to split out the code into a separate DLL, which will be named after the VC system it interfaces to, and registered in a Category.

Comment: I generally build one project containing the IDL for the interfaces, which builds the P/S library, and each implementation imports the IDL from there and defines `coclass`es.

Comment: Is there any chance you've missed an #define and you're accidentally `__declspec(dllimport)` ing some of your own functions back? Or similarly you've got a `@pragma(comment, lib)` for the .lib in code that's being included in the DLL build? I'd try #erroring all the import parts of your header files. (Or is this literally just the stub code generated from the IDL?)

Comment: This is just the stub code, plus a `.def` file to export the usual suspects.

Comment: Are there any `<ProjectReference>` elements in your project file that point to the version control project?

Comment: @SimonRichter - Nevermind... just realized it is its own import library.  Don't see how that detail got away from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but worth a look...

Open up your vcxproj file and look for the @(Midl) item.  Modify it by trying one of these three pieces of item metadata and see how the behavior changes, it may put you on the right path:

```
  <Midl Include="My.idl">
    <LinkCompiled>false</LinkCompiled>
    <LibCompiled>false</LibCompiled>
    <ImpLibCompiled>false</ImpLibCompiled>
  </Midl>
```